# what is the meaning of -s in Perl and how does it work?

Tags: perl

I have a perl program like

```
  $var= "hello world";
  $var = -s $var;
  print $var;
```

When we print the value of $var, it shows a error like

```
     Use of uninitialized value $var in print at line 3.
```

Can anyone explain how this works. What is the -s does? Is it a function? I couldn't find snyhing about it in perldoc.

Comment: Can you share the link or source where did you find it, I have seen first time `-s` using like this.

Comment: All I could find this:

`-s`
enables rudimentary switch parsing for switches on the command line after the program name but before any filename arguments (or before an argument of --). Any switch found there is removed from @ARGV and sets the corresponding variable in the Perl program. The following program prints "1" if the program is invoked with a -xyz switch, and "abc" if it is invoked with -xyz=abc.
  `#!/usr/bin/perl -s`
  `if ($xyz) { print "$xyz\n" }`

Comment: I found this in O'Reilly perl cookbook PDF and used in my program. It is available in section 5.2 "Testing for the presence of a key in a hash"

Comment: You completely misunderstood the example and took the wrong parts of the code and used them incorrectly to make your code above that makes no sense. The book even has an explanation of its code "Take, for instance, a program to look up file sizes given a list of files as input. "

Comment: I thought I am undefining the value by using -s. It sounded like s (substitute) and - (nothing), such that replacing the string with undefined value. Now I understood. Thanks :)

Comment: @AbhiNickz: The definition f0r `-s` that you're quoting is from [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html). It's a command line option. The code from the original post is clearly not using it as a command line option. The correct definition for this usage is [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).

Comment: By the way, when `-s` returns undef, it does not necessarily indicate the file is does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-s` is an oddly named function documented in [`-X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html). But despite the dash in its name, `-s` is just like any other function.

`-s` returns the size of the file provided as an argument. On error, it returns `undef` and sets `$!`.

To find out what error you are getting, check if the size is undefined.

```
defined( my $size = -s $qfn )
   or die("Can't stat \"$qfn\": $!\n");
```

In this case, it's surely because `hello world` isn't a path to a file.

Answer (score 9):

The `-s` file test operator accepts either a file name string or a valid opened file handle, and returns the size of the file in bytes. If the file doesn't exist (I presume you have no file called `hello world`) then it returns `undef`

It is documented in [perldoc -f -X](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

There is also a perl command-line switch `-s` which is unrelated. It is documented in [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches). That is the documentation that you have found, but it is irrelevant to using `-s` within a Perl program

Answer (score 4):

`-s` is one of many file tests available in Perl. This particular test returns file size in bytes, so it can be used to check if file is empty or not.

In your sample code the test returned `undef`, as it could not find file named `hello world`.

You can read more about file tests in Perl here: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html